# Regular expression for 12 hours time format

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a regular expression for time pattern in Python: hours [1-12] followed by `:`, then minutes [00:59] followed by an optional space and `am` or `PM` in upper- or lowercase.

Here is the code:

```
def check_time(text):
       pattern = r"^(1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):([0-5]?[0-9])(\s?[AP]M)?$ "
       result = re.search(pattern, text)
       return result != None

       print(check_time("12:45pm")) # Expected True
       print(check_time("9:59 AM")) # Expected True
       print(check_time("6:60am")) # Expected False
       print(check_time("five o'clock")) # Expected False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the following changes:

- Use a case insensitive search, pass `re.I` flag
- Remove the space after `$`
- You may return the boolean result by using `bool(re.search(...))`
- To avoid the overhead related to capture group memory allocation, you may replace all your capturing groups to non-capturing ones (`(...)` -> `(?:...)`).

See [Python code example](https://ideone.com/hxUfL5):

```
def check_time(text):
  pattern = r"^(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):(?:[0-5]?[0-9])(?:\s?[AP]M)?$"
  return bool(re.search(pattern, text, flags=re.I))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
def check_time(text):
  pattern = r"^(?:1[0-2]|[1-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9])(?:\s?[APap][Mm])?$"
  result = re.search(pattern, text)
  return result != None

print(check_time("12:45pm")) # True
print(check_time("9:59 AM")) # True
print(check_time("6:60am")) # False
print(check_time("five o'clock")) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def check_time(text):
  pattern = r'^1[0-2]|[1-9]:[0-5][0-9](\s?[APap][Mm])$'
  result = re.search(pattern, text)
  return result != None

print(check_time("12:45pm")) # True
print(check_time("9:59 AM")) # True
print(check_time("6:60am")) # False
print(check_time("five o'clock")) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def check_time(text):
    pattern = r'[1-9][0-2]?:[0-5][0-9] ?[apAP][mM]'
    result = re.search(pattern, text)
    return result != None

print(check_time("12:45pm")) # True
print(check_time("9:59 AM")) # True
print(check_time("6:60am")) # False
print(check_time("five o'clock")) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def check_time(text):
  pattern = r'([1-9]|1[012]):([0-5][0-9])\s?(am|pm)'
  result = re.search(pattern, text, flags=re.I)
  return result != None

print(check_time("12:45pm")) # True
print(check_time("9:59 AM")) # True
print(check_time("6:60am")) # False
print(check_time("five o'clock")) # False
```

**Explanation**
`([1-9]|1[012])` => [1-9] match's  single digits which start from 1 not from 0
this or condition 1[012] match's two digits ranges 10-12
eg: `1:`23 or `10`:30

`:([0-5][0-9])` => `:` you know, match's the range 00 - 59 rules out 60
`\s?(am|pm)` =>  since space is optional so `\s?` (am|pm) capture day or
evening eg. am or pm
`result = re.search(pattern, text, flags=re.I)` =>  note flags.I is used as case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Actually! In most of the current answers, I noticed:

- Some limited their regex by using `^` metacharacter to test against only the clock that is first of an inserted text.
- And those didn't use `^` metacharacter, they didn't think of cases like wrong hour digits:'112:50 am'!

Here is my suggestion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

def check_time(text):
    pattern = r"\b(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9] ?[APap][Mm]" # in case of using re.I flag then change the last part to: [ap][m]
    result = re.search(pattern, text)  # Or use re.IGNORECASE
    return result[0] if result else 'F'


print(1, "T: ", check_time("12:45pm"))  # True
print(2, "T: ", check_time("9:59 AM"))  # True
print(3, "F: ", check_time("6:60am"))  # False
print(4, "F: ", check_time("five o'clock"))  # False
print(5, "T: ", check_time("6:10am"))  # True
print(6, "F: ", check_time("52:45pm"))  # False
print(7, "F: ", check_time("19:59 AM"))  # False
print(8, "F: ", check_time("26:50am"))  # False
print(9, "T: ", check_time("10:45pm"))  # True
print(10, "F: ", check_time("10:95pm"))  # False
print(11, "T: ", check_time("11:05pm"))  # True
print(12, "F: ", check_time("11:5pm"))  # False
print(13, "F: ", check_time("112:05pm"))  # False
print(14, "F: ", check_time("1112:05pm"))  # False
print(15, "F: ", check_time("1112:0125pm"))  # False
print(16, "T: ", check_time("01:25pm"))  # True
```

Happy Coding